# не работает код для бота который скачивает видео из ютуба(python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, youtube, pytube

делаю бота для телеграма, он должен по введенной ссылке скачивать видео, пока бот тестовый и ссылку уже введена. Уже были ошибки такого типа, они вызваны тем, что не каждое видео формата mp4, однако сейчас я подобрал видео формата mp4, а ошибка все равно осталась

```py
import telebot
from pytube import YouTube
import sys
import random

print('Введите токен:')
tok = '1253588512:AAEfDNBJC0a0ToG8P2DfzDk_gp3U94zXvxU'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tok)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    if 'привет' in message.text.lower():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, я могу скчать для тебя видео с ютуба, просто отправь мне ссылку, но учти, что я могу скчать не все видео, а только mp4")

    elif 'https' in message.text.lower():
        url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90KZnwrVMgY'
        yt = YouTube(url)
        print(f'Download video {yt.title!r}: {url}')
        streams = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution='480p').order_by('resolution')

        video = streams[-1]

        print('Stream url:', video.url)
        video.download()
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Готово!")
                
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши Привет.")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

а вот фрагмент ошибки:

```
  streams[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Можете привести полный текст ошибки?

Comment: File "C:\Users\chuva\OneDrive\Документы\yandex luceum\web\templates\psp_bot2281337.py", line 23, in get_text_messages
    video = streams[-1]
  File "C:\Users\chuva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pytube\query.py", line 350, in __getitem__
    return self.fmt_streams[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: полностью ошибка не влезает по количеству символов

Answer (score 1):

всё дело в том, что видео по вашей ссылке из примера  не имеет `progressive=True` в 480p:

`[<Stream: itag="135" mime_type="video/mp4" res="480p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.4d401e" progressive="False" type="video">]`

`[<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">]`

```
print(yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution='480p').order_by('resolution'))
>>> Про пикапы, ремонт, и б/у машины.
[]

print(yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution='720p').order_by('resolution'))
>> Про пикапы, ремонт, и б/у машины.
[<Stream: itag="22" mime_type="video/mp4" res="720p" fps="30fps" vcodec="avc1.64001F" acodec="mp4a.40.2" progressive="True" type="video">]
```

поэтому список пуст и вы не можете обратиться к пустому списку по `video = streams[-1]`